# Multiple language support in web app backend

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

Not having too much experience with this, I will ask you for advice on handling multiple language support in an web application

The front end is AngularJs, the backend is .NET with WebAPI.
I've implemented front end translations using an angularjs framework and json 
files for the transaltions. It works nicely but I have come upon some drawbacks.

- the json translation files are all being sent with every page load or refresh. If the number of translation files increseas or if the content increases, this could turn out to be inefficient.
- i don't have access to translations in the back end, when I'm generating file exports, for example.

Any advice on how to handle translations efficiently on the front end and also on the back end would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend use angular-translate https://angular-translate.github.io/ It allows you to load translations asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

First install the angular-translate package:

```
bower install angular angular-translate
```

This will create a angular-translate.js / angular-translate.min.js file

Include the file in the html page.

Add the lib to module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('Multilingual', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
```

In config part add this:

```
$translateProvider
  .translations('ar', {
    'HELLO': 'مرحبا'
  })
  .translations('en', {
    'HELLO': 'Hello'
  })
  .preferredLanguage('ar');
```

Use `$translate.use('ar');` in the controller to switch languages .